# Why choose D* over Dijkstra?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, search-algorithms, efficiency

I understand the basis of A* as being a derivative of Dijkstra, however, I recently found out about D*. From Wikipedia, I can understand the algorithm. What I do not understand is why I would use D* over Dijkstra. To my understanding, Dijkstra gives a best path and D* works backwards from the end goal, but unlike A* it seems to do many calculations, so it doesn't seem as efficient.

Comment: Dijkstra is designed when the graph is known, from wikipedia, apparently D* is designed for unknown terrain?

Comment: i mean in order to calculate the path, you need to know something... so if its unknown terrain, you still need to scan it (i found out about D* in autonomous vehicle research), and then i imagine you get the nodes from the scan.  either way if you dont know the terrain how do you start at the end

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main reason for choosing D* is that it is *incremental*. Basically, when your initial route gets blocked, an incremental search algorithm is able to take advantage of the previous calculations. Dijkstra doesn't do this; it needs to recompute everything from scratch. Such an incremental approach is often used in robotics, navigation, and planning.

This is the short answer. For much more, I think you would be interested in [How do the state-of-the-art pathfinding algorithms for changing graphs (D*, D*-Lite, LPA*, etc) differ?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/11855/how-do-the-state-of-the-art-pathfinding-algorithms-for-changing-graphs-d-d-l)